# Adding fragments via transaction

Tags: android, android-fragments, transactions

When I use transaction.add(), why is that I can only add a R.id.xxx layout, instead of a R.layout.xxx?

What's the difference between a layout with an R.id.xxx and a layout using R.layout.xxx?

Also, in my fragment in onCreateView, which view am I supposed to inflate, the activity_main layout or the fragment layout, and why?

Thanks!

Comment: 1)transaction.add() is a function to add fragment to container view with id, not to create fragment with a layout resource id; 2) inflate fragment layout, this is to create fragment layout, not activity layout.

Comment: So, what I did was create a layout inside a layout in activity_main. I called it R.id.fragment. What's the difference between creating a layout with an id inside another layout, and creating a new xml file that's a layout. So, R.id.fragment versus R.layout.fragment?

Comment: @bluexmarker : What type of layout is `R.id.fragment` in your `activity_main.xml`? A `FrameLayout`? If so that's your placeholder for the `Fragment` and it's where you add the `Fragment`. In `onCreateView(...)` the `Fragment` has already been instantiated and you then simply inflate and add a `View` to it. In essence the `View` is likely to be a `ViewGroup` such as a `RelativeLayout` or a `LinearLayout` etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are three separate questions.

> 1. When I use transaction.add(), why is that I can only add a R.id.xxx layout, instead of a R.layout.xxx?

I presume you are referring [FragmentTransaction.add(containerViewId, fragment)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#add(int,%20android.app.Fragment,%20java.lang.String))

- to add dynamically a fragment, it will use your activity layout (there are some exclusions but this is a general rule). The activity layout needs to have a layout with an id which you need to supply as a first parameter in the method

> 2. What's the difference between a layout with an R.id.xxx and a layout using R.layout.xxx?

- R.layout.xxx points to `res/layout/xxx.xml` file and will use it as a layout (inflated view)
- R.id.xxx is unique id bound to a view or layout in any of `res/layout` files.

> 3. Also, in my fragment in onCreateView, which view am I supposed to inflate, the activity_main layout or the fragment layout, and why?

- the fragment layout
- fragment wraps a view (or layout in your case) and will pass it to be added into the layout with above id (when calling `FragmentTransaction.add()`

Comment: For question 2, why is that when I use fragmentTransaction.add(), I can't use R.layout.fragment and I can only use R.id.fragment, even though they are both layouts? In other words, why doesn't R.layout.fragment act as an ID for the layout that's implemented in the xml file?

Comment: `R` is the class presentation of folder `res` i.e. `R.layout.fragment` is `res/layout/fragment.xml`. `R.id.fragment` corresponds to any view with `id=fragment`.  
`FragmentTransaction.add()` expects a view id as a first param (not a layout file). 
This id points to the parent view which will hold your fragment view. And the fragment view is from `Fragment.onCreateView()`

Comment: I think the frustration becomes of using `layout` as naming for different purposes: 1) layout as a file from `res/layout` or `R.layout.xxx` 2) layout as a view which extends `ViewGroup` and can hold any other views. Think about (2) as view container rather layout. This should clear the mist.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you cannot refer to a layout with R.id.xxx;
R.id.xxx is the id reference for the element of the R.layout.xxx that you want to add to R.layout.xxx.

About the second question, I assume that you want to inflate the fragment view with a layout. So you have to inflate the view with R.layout.xxx that you want to display in your view.
You can find some very clear explanations about it here:
http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html
Hope this helps.